# How to restrict the size of the file being uploaded on to the AWS S3 service using presigned urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using an AWS S3 presigned url to upload picture from a client (mobile app).
I want to prevent the user to upload large files.
Is there a way to limit the file size of an uploaded file?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out "content-length-range" in s3 policy.
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

> The conditions in a POST policy is an array of objects, each of which is used to validate the contents of the uploaded object. You can use these conditions to restrict what is allowed in the request. Each form field that you specify in a form (except x-amz-signature, file, policy, and field names that have an x-ignore- prefix) must appear in the list of conditions.
>
> content-length-range
>   The minimum and maximum allowable size for the uploaded content.
>   This condition supports content-length-range condition match type.

Comment: Is there a way to do this while creating a pre-signed URL for uploading an object?

Comment: Thanks @Nat, I've explored 'GeneratePresignedUrlRequest ' API already, it does not provide a way to specify 'content-length-range'.

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to set up a policy first with content-length-range and then sign a url with that policy

Comment: I know a policy can be set, but only via browser upload or the PUT object API. But there's no way I could find to set policy via the API to generate pre-signed url (I'm using the Java SDK, GeneratePresignedUrl class does not have such a method). Do you have a sample code of this?

Comment: @NikhilPatil will this help? https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/PresignedPostPolicy.java Its minio-java client library PresignedPostPolicy.java example, It is compatible with AWS S3 API. Disclaimer: i work for minio.

Comment: @Niks i tried with this tutorial https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-s3-post-signed-urls/ and its works

Comment: Is this in KB or bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem perfectly! Though, the POST policy can work, but use presigned urls is more comfortable.

I use **nodejs** as backend. And use **getSignedUrl** to limit the size of upload file.

It just need modify three line of aws-sdk code. And I have tried, it can work very well.

I don't know why aws-sdk of nodejs don't support it. If there is some reason, please share to me.

**first, open "node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4.js", comment the following two line**
[image]

**second, open "node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js", comment the following one line**
[image]

**third, write the code to generate presigned url and upload file**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, even if this works, commenting out code in your dependencies is a terrible option for almost every use case. The change won't propagate unless you check in the dependency. And any other devs you work with won't be aware of this special change and are likely to try to update the dep. Also this looks like it requires knowing the _exact_ size, not just adding a limit.

Comment: yes, it's just for a hack use, and the limit usage can be realized by sign when post a request to backend.