# Uploading file to AWS S3 with limited file size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

i have a service that need to upload file to S3 bucket. So far we're using S3 PUT presigned URL. So the upload flow is something like this:

[Upload flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNOgw.png)

For context, the client here is another service not web application.

My goal is to control maximum file size that can uploaded to S3.

Googling around, I found that PUT presigned URL cannot control maximum file size that can be uploaded.
Alternatively, having a dedicated service as a proxy to handle file upload, but its is expensive since we handle huge number of traffic in production env.

Is there any alternative flow for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like there is a discussion here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991275/limit-size-of-objects-while-uploading-to-amazon-s3-using-pre-signed-url